# Real-time Updates of a Group Wall

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, real-time

Is it possible to use [real-time updates](http://developers.beta.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/) from facebook to get updates from a Group Wall?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NO. You can poll to FB's graph api how often do you need, but it's not yet "realtime"

Answer (score 1):

So far only users, permissions, and pages according to their [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/).  Although they plan to add more so check back with them or ask them [here](https://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers/).